ngPackagr define allowedCommonJsDependencies
In Angular when using a CommonJS dependency like moment one gets a warning like
CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.dev/tools/cli/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Following this link to the official angular docs we can see that we can specify these dependencies in a special field in the build section:
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
     "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
        "lodash"
     ]
     …
   }
   …
},

Then the warning is gone.
However when we develop a library which uses a CommonJs dependency I did not find any setting in ngPackagr to do this. This results in the same warning for consumers of the library.
Is there any possibility to set allowedCommonJsDependencies in ngPackagr?

there is no direct configuration  in angular for allowedCommonJsDependencies like in Angular applications yeah you can replace CommonJS dependencies with their ES Module counterparts like lodash-es

The package usually exists within a workspace, that has an angular.json, in that angular.json, try setting the allowedCommonJsDependencies to the CommonJS or AMD dependencies modules you use in your library and run a build.
Check if the warnings disappear.
Angular Docs - Creating libraries
"projects": {
  …
  "my-lib": {
    "root": "projects/my-lib",
    "sourceRoot": "projects/my-lib/src",
    "projectType": "library",
    "prefix": "lib",
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
        "options": {
          "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
            "lodash"
          ]
          …
        }
        …
    …


Unfortunately you can not set allowedCommonJsDependencies as option for ngPackagr builder, see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/builders/ng-packagr/schema.json

@Mikelgo this is for the angular.json that is present in the parent directory (workspace) of your library.
